# How can I pass an onclick event to the deepest element if two elements are nested?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
        <div class='child-of-child'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I then execute the following javascript to add even listeners to my `div`s:

```
var addOnClickListenerToSelfAndChildren = function(el) {
    el.onclick = onclickfunction;
    var children = el.children;
    for (var i = children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        addOnClickListenerToSelfAndChildren(children[i]);
    }
}

var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0];
addOnClickListenerToSelfAndChildren(parent);
```

This works great, except that I would like ONLY THE DEEPEST node to register the click. This means that if `child-of-child` receives the click event, then 'child' and 'parent' will ignore it. How can this be achieved?

Here is a little picture to clarify things: 
[image: Graphical representation of problem]

If child receives onclick, I don't want to trigger parent's onclick. However if I click in the `parent` region, then the click must be registered by 'parent'. I guess you could say I want the children to be 'click opaque'.

Comment: why not `var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('child-of-child'); `?

Comment: @Özgür Ersil: its not universal way

Comment: Do not add event listeners to elements that you dont want them to trigger then I guess. Just add it to the deepest child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `getElementsByClassName` will return `array-like` nodelist not `DOMElement` and you can not access `children` property of the `NodeList` because there isn't any!

In this example, you are dealing with the `first-element`, hence access it using `[0]`

```js
var onclickfunction = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); //to prevent bubling of the events
  alert(this.getAttribute('class'));
}
var addOnClickListenerToSelfAndChildren = function(el) {
  el.onclick = onclickfunction;
  var children = el.children;
  for (var i = children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    addOnClickListenerToSelfAndChildren(children[i]);
  }
}

var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0];
addOnClickListenerToSelfAndChildren(parent);
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
    <div class='child-of-child'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work rather well. How can I ensure the event propagates from children to parents and not the opposite way?

Comment: Events can never propagate opposite way! Let me know if you find any difficulty..

Answer (score 4):

I feel you only need to register click on the parent.

```
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('parent');
parent[0].onclick=function(e){
  //'e.target' gets the origin of the event. 'this' gets the parent object
  console.log(e.target);
}
```

with `e.target` you can get from where did the click originated and you can do the logic depending on that. You can also use `this` to get the parent object

Comment: This pattern is known as [Event Deleation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) and I think it would be the best approach here.

Comment: This is also a very good answer, except that sometimes my child will NOT have a click listener on it, which is important for me to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onclickfunction(e) {
    ... code ...
    if (<event is handled>) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

e.stopPropagation() prevents invoking parent's elements listeners.